# Write a file copying and moving function with both the arguments are strings for Android

Tags: android, file, filenames, copying

I want to write a file copying and moving function with both  the argruments  are strings. Is there any quick way? Best if it also keeps the file created date time.

```
String sourceFilename, destFileName;
            sourceFilename = "/Download/log.txt";
            destFileName= "/Download/log.bak";
            moveFileByName(sourceFilename, destFileName);
```

Comment: not clear , do you want rename file and move it to another location ?

Comment: You should just google this site for copyfile and you will find suitable code.

Comment: there seems no simple function call, I have to do it wet @Heshan Sandeepa : both copying and moving are required; just find that I need to use "/sdcard/Download/log.txt", why there is no equal of renameto()?

Comment: I want to update the dest file date time with dest.setLastModified(source.lastModified()); but seems not working?